# Chrome sometimes becomes unresponsive on clicking a button on my website

Tags: java, performance, google-chrome, gwt

My website is made through java and Google web toolkit

When i click on button chrome sometimes becomes unresponsive and i have to kill the page ultimately.

It never happens on firefox and IE.

Is it some cache problem or plugin problem or something else.

Comment: Is it still bugged after deploy on Tomcat (or another one) ?

Comment: i have seen log on tomcat . There is no exception or error . This is problem of Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly start looking at your server logs to verify that this is a client based problem rather than bad parameters.

Then verify that HTML/JS is correctly formed and has no errors.

Lastly I suggest to you to use Chrome Developer Tool (Right click) and to choose the profiling tab to collect JS CPU Profiling.